# WCF - Built-in types not being reused

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service library and another library that has a service reference to it in VS2010. "Reuse types in all referenced assemblies" is selected on the reference properties. When I scope in the client proxy namespace in the consuming library code, I get this error:

> WCF Error 'Exception' is an ambiguous reference between
>   'System.Exception' and 'My.Namespace.CoreService.Exception'

... where `My.Namespace.CoreService` is the namespace of the service reference. My service library does not define a type called `Exception`; the line in question is a catch block for the built-in `Exception` type.

Strangely, when I added the service reference, four datasources were automatically created in the consuming project for built in types (`System.Data.DataSet`, `System.Data.DataTable`, `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message` and `System.Xml.XmlElement`). These four types are used as return types in some of my OperationContracts.

Based on this it seems to me that the built-in types aren't being reused across the assembly boundaries. This doesn't make any sense to me, can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a type in the generated proxy code called exception (something the service was using as a type in its contract)? If so, you will have to fully qualify the types or use aliases

You can check to see the generated code my clicking on Show all files in solution explorer and opening up the service reference and reference.svcmap until you see reference.cs - this is the generated proxy code

Comment: There is a type in reference.cs called Exception, but it's not a type that my service uses in any contracts:
`public partial class Exception : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {`

Comment: How is it used in the generated code? Does one of the generated classes have a property of type Exception or something along those lines? Could the service is a DataContract that has its Name property set to "Exception"?

Comment: Reference.cs also derives SystemException from this class:

`public partial class SystemException : Exception {}`
And the following attribute is applied to virtually every operation contract in reference.cs:

`[System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(Exception))]`